# Access `DownstreamReRoute` within `DelegatingHandler` in Ocelot

Tags: .net-core, ocelot

Is it possible to access the `DownstreamReRoute` object within a `DelegatingHandler` in Ocelot? I have a `DelegatingHandler` instance and I'd like to slightly alter its behaviour based on the downstream reroute that is being called. I *could* do this based on the URL of the `HttpRequestMessage` that is passed into the `SendAsync()` method but I'd prefer to do it by the downstream reroute key, if possible.

I've had a look at the dependencies added by the `OcelotBuilder` to see if there's something I could inject to then query the current reroute but it doesn't seem possible.

E.g. If I have a `DelegatingHandler`

```cs
public class MyDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
  protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  { 
    // access reRoute here?
  }
}
```

and config (required fields removed for brevity)

```
"ReRoutes": [
{
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/downstream/foo",
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/foo",
  "Key": "FooKey",
  "DelegatingHandlers": [ "MyDelegatingHandler" ]
},
{
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/downstream/bar",
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/bar",
  "Key": "BarKey",
  "DelegatingHandlers": [ "MyDelegatingHandler" ]
}]
```

Is it possible to know whether I'm calling `FooKey` or `BarKey` reRoute from a delegatingHandler?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this by adding a `PreQueryStringBuilderMiddleware` handler when configuring Ocelot.

By doing this I could set a property in the HttpContext.Items collection that contains the reRouteKey. This can then be picked up by further processors in the request.

E.g. (without null handling etc)

```
app.UseOcelot(cfg =>
  cfg.PreQueryStringBuilderMiddleware = (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.HttpContext.Items["ReRouteKey"] = ctx.DownstreamReRoute.Key;
    return next.Invoke();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution to this, you must use `IHttpContextAccessor`.

On `MyDelegatingHandler.cs`

```
using Ocelot.Middleware;

public class MyDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;
    public MyHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var downstreamRoute = _httpContext.HttpContext.Items?.DownstreamRouteHolder()?.Route?.DownstreamRoute?.FirstOrDefault();
        if (downstreamRoute != null)
        {
             if(downstreamRoute.Key == "FooKey")
             {
                  //Do something
             } else if (downstreamRoute.Key == "BarKey")
             {
                  //Do something else
             }
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to register `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` on `Startup.cs`

***NB**: To be specific my config was "Routes" but not "ReRoutes". I believe it going to work for "ReRoutes" config too.*